# trying to copy data from one textbox to another on blur or click isn't working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to know if this script is correct for trying to copy text from one box to another using a radio button to activate the function.  because it isn't working for me. They are two different forms i don't know if that matters. all they are is text boxes and i want the data from the form TOTALS to copy to the form profit.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function data_copy()
{

if(document.TOTALS.copy[0].checked){
document.profit.SOLDTO1.value=document.TOTALS.SOLDTO.value;
document.profit.['ACCNT#1'].value=document.TOTALS.ACCNT#.value;
document.profit.INVNUM1.value=document.TOTALS.INVNUM.value;
document.profit.SLM1.value=document.TOTALS.SLM.value;
document.profit.totfaccost1.value=document.TOTALS.totfaccost.value;
document.profit.tot_frt_cost1.value=document.TOTALS.tot_frt_cost.value;
document.profit.totlandcost1.value=document.TOTALS.totlandcost.value;
}else{
document.profit.SOLDTO1.value="";
document.profit.['ACCNT#1'].value="";
document.profit.INVNUM1.value="";
document.profit.SLM1.value="";
document.profit.totfaccost1.value="";
document.profit.totlandcost1.value="";

}

}

</script>


 Click to fill out profit analysis<input type="radio" name=copy value='yes' onclick="data_copy()";>
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
document.profit.ACCNT#1.value="";
```

is a syntax error. Try:

```
document.profit['ACCNT#1'].value = "";
```

Both places you reference that need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

the hash `#` in `document.TOTALS.ACCNT#.value` is not a valid variable name character, so this won't parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to use `document.getElementById` to find elements in the document:

```
document.getElementById("SOLDTO1").value = document.getElementById("SOLDTO").value;
```

I would also remove any hash marks or special characters from the element names and/or IDs.